# jQuery animation issues due to scrolling restarting the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a problem with a nav bar sliding in when the user scrolls down. My code works - yet if you keep scrolling (up and down, or down very quickly) the bar moves really slowly instead of the speed it should. I think this is because the function restarts itself even though it is halfway through the animation, so it has to move half the distance yet keeps the same time as if it has to travel the whole distance. I found several possibilities but they all cleared the queue of animations which I cannot do as if I scroll to the top before the down animation has completed, the nav bar will still be visible even though it should not. So basically I want the nav bar to slide in smoothly even if I keep scrolling down, yet there needs to be something stopping me from scrolling to the top with the nav bar still visible. Thanks

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bhaZ6/8/

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = 220;
    var duration = 500;

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            jQuery('#nav').stop(true).animate({'top': '0'}, duration, 'linear');
        } else {
            jQuery('#nav').stop(true).animate({'top': '-72px'}, duration, 'linear');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to set some flags whenever the scroll reaches the point of animation, and only do the animation once.

Comment: @adeneo thanks so much I got it now

Comment: @VotetoClose that gets rid of the smooth animation for me. Thanks for your help but I have fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the animation needs to only run once, I created a variable called position which restricts the 'down animation' running more than once until an 'up animation' is called and vice vera. Thanks to [adeno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) for the idea

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = 220;
    var duration = 300;
    var position = 'up';

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset && position === 'up') {
            jQuery('#nav').stop(true).animate({'top': '0'}, duration, 'linear');
            position = 'down';
        } else if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < offset && position === 'down'){
            jQuery('#nav').stop(true).animate({'top': '-72px'}, duration, 'linear');
            position = 'up';
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
});
```